# Matrix derivative of transpose

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

While I am able to see the differentiation of a matrix expression in the matrix cookbook of this form,

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{c}}{\partial \mathbf{X}}  =  \mathbf{X} (\mathbf{b} \mathbf{c}^T + \mathbf{c} \mathbf{b}^T)$$

I am unable to figure out the derivative of the numerator's transpose from the cookbook i.e.

$$ \frac{\partial \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{b}}{\partial \mathbf{X}} = \ ?$$

Comment: Note: $(b^TX^TXc)^T = c^T(b^TX^TX)^T = c^T(X^TX)^Tb = c^T(X^TX)b$ which is not the same as $bXX^Tc^T$

Comment: The above can be seen because if $X$ is an $n x m$ matrix, $X^TX$ is an $m x m$ matrix whose transpose is $m x m$ and $XX^T$ is an $n x n$ matrix whose transpose is also an $n x n$ matrix. For an actual example, use: $ X = \begin{bmatrix}
    3      & 1 \\
    -1      & 5\\
   4      & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: If you consider *column* vectors $b$ and $c$, then $bXX^Tc^T$ is likely not well defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f(X) = b^T X X^T c$ we have
$$Df(X)[H] = b^T H X^T c + b^T X H^T c = tr(X^T cb^T H) + tr(X^Tbc^TH) .$$
So we have
$$ \frac{\partial f(X)}{\partial X} = (bc^T + cb^T) X .$$

Comment: I understand the concept of directional derivative and the cyclic permutation you did to proof but can you please share some resource that can help me 
 understand the concept better and help me solve more complicated expressions like above.

Comment: @learner I only used the product rule. Basically you can do most stuff with product rule, chain rule and inverse function theorem.